# What happens to a hydrogen atom under an intense gravitational field (or intense acceleration)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, hydrogen

I'm curious how the observed quantum-mechanical properties of a hydrogen atom would change under very high gravitational fields.  Do the energy levels change?  Do the chemical bonding properties change?  Does that atom become asymmetric (electrically polar)? etc.
In the context of a black hole, what happens to a hydrogen atom moving slowly towards the event horizon versus what happens to a hydrogen atom in free-fall, where presumably tidal forces ultimately rip it apart.

Comment: See [One-electron atom as a probe of spacetime curvature](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.22.1922), a 1980 paper by Leonard Parker. A more recent study focusing on black holes is [The Energy-Level Shifts of a Stationary Hydrogen Atom in Static External Gravitational Field with Schwarzschild Geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1571).

Comment: Unfortunately, neither paper answers all your questions. But they’re a start on what is known about this.

Comment: @G. Smith Both references say that generally the energy levels shift in a strong gravitational field.  But I don't understand the statment from the second reference: "In this paper we investigate energy-level shifts of a stationary hydrogen atom in static external gravitational field. With the calculations we find the results in this case is same with a hydrogen atom freely falling along a radical geodesic[3]."  I thought that "freely falling" meant the atom sees no gravitational field?

Comment: *I thought that "freely falling" meant the atom sees no gravitational field?* That’s not how I’d put it. It’s falling toward the black hole *because* of the hole’s gravity.

Comment: @G. Smith Surely the implication here then is that the shifts in energy levels are not due to the gravitational field, but are due to tidal effects (derivative of field)?

Comment: I think we getting into semantics of what “gravitational field” means in GR. The shifts are due to the Riemann curvature, so, yes, they are “tidal effects”.

Answer (score 5):

I have not found an explicit analysis of the atom wave function, but [one can work with the Schrödinger equation in accelerated frames](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C9707077/papers/art34.pdf) and [it looks like acceleration does change energy levels](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05495).

[Acceleration can cause excitation of hydrogen atoms](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604116), producing a spontaneous emission rate $\propto a^2$. This happens because it interacts with the electromagnetic vacuum, and when you accelerate the vacuum starts exhibiting temperature (the Unruh effect). [This also happens near black holes](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.76.044023). [For sufficient accelerations the proton can even undergo inverse beta decay](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9901008): it gets enough energy from the vacuum interaction that it can "decay" to a neutron.

Comment: I'm not sure how to relate those first two references to a hydrogen atom.  In the original question, do I need to clarify whether I am observing/measuring the energy levels sitting alongside the atom or sitting a long way away outside the gravitational field (not accelerating)?

Answer (score 0):

A recent paper has studied [Schrodinger equation in a general curved spacetime geometry](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218271822500183). It has answered some of the questions you asked. When the hydrogen atom freely falls in or is scattered by a black hole (or a mass distribution), it gets excited by the Riemann tensor.